# Make a new list in CSV without using pandas: return UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, encoding

I am trying to make a new list in my existing csv file (not using pandas).
Here is my code:

```
with open ('/Users/Weindependent/Desktop/dataset/albumlist.csv','r') as case0:
    reader = csv.DictReader(case0)
    album = []
    for row in reader:
        album.append(row)
print ("Number of albums is:",len(album))
```

The CSV file was downloaded from the [Rolling Stone's Top 500 albums data set on data.world](https://data.world/notgibs/rolling-stones-top-500-albums).

My logic is to create an empty list named album and have all the records in this list. But it seems the line of `for row in reader` has some issue.

the error message I got is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 1040: invalid continuation byte
```

Can anyone let me know what I did wrong?

Comment: This can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752313/unicodedecodeerror-in-python-3-when-importing-a-csv-file

Comment: The data file you are reading from is probably not UTF-8 encoded. You'll have to specify a different encoding with `encoding="...."`. What encoding to use, we can't tell you, sorry.

Comment: How can I tell what type the file is encoded?

Comment: Where did the dataset come from? Did they document this perhaps?

Comment: Since you got as far as 1040 bytes into the CSV until you hit a decoding error, chances are the file is also encoded with a single-byte encoding, the most popular of which is `cp1252`. Give it a try first.

Comment: Yes. sorry my bad: https://data.world/notgibs

Comment: So, the Rolling Stones list? "Copied from Kaggle", and "No definitions added for the 1 file and the 6 columns in this dataset.". You'll have to ask the author of the dataset what they think was used as an encoding.

Comment: Here is the Kaggle source: https://www.kaggle.com/notgibs/500-greatest-albums-of-all-time-rolling-stone; I'd check the kernels to see if any of them specify a codec when opening the dataset.

Comment: Gah, the [top-voted kernel just clobbers the codepoints it can't read](https://www.kaggle.com/ictylor/rolling-stone-500-analysis-simple-code/code). So does the next one (`encoding='ASCII', errors='ignore'`). Not a great approach.

Comment: Others use `albumlist = pd.read_csv('../input/albumlist.csv', encoding='cp1256')` or `pd.read_csv("../input/albumlist.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1")`, two different Latin codec variations. Since almost *any* Latin-based codec will work that may or may not be correct.

Comment: @blhsing: and that's 1040 bytes into a *single buffer page*. It could be anywhere in the file. It is probably a Latin-variant.

Comment: The first line that fails contains `"Reggae,\xcaPop,\xcaFolk, World, & Country,\xcaStage & Screen"` as the genre. Those 0xCA bytes look like a data error to me, *or* they were meant to be [U+00A0 NO-BREAK-SPACE characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A0/index.htm), meaning this would be encoded as one of the mac_centeuro, mac_croatian, mac_cyrillic, mac_greek, mac_iceland, mac_latin2, mac_roman, mac_romanian and mac_turkish group of codecs. Weird.

Comment: All but one non-ASCII row use the 0xCA bytes. The one exception uses 0x89 in the album name "Honky Ch\x89teau", so [Elton John's "Honky Château"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honky_Ch%C3%A2teau), confirming that this must be a mac encoding, only the mac_arabic, mac_croatian, mac_farsi, mac_greek, mac_iceland, mac_roman, mac_romanian and mac_turkish codecs encode the [U+00E2 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00E2/index.htm) codepoint to 0x89.

Comment: So the intersection of those two sets is mac_arabic, mac_croatian, mac_farsi, mac_greek, mac_iceland, mac_roman, mac_romanian and mac_turkish., and `mac_roman` is the most likely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file in the correct codec; UTF-8 is not the correct one. The dataset doesn't specify it, but I have determined that the most likely codec is `mac_roman`:

```
with open ('/Users/Weindependent/Desktop/dataset/albumlist.csv', 'r', encoding='mac_roman') as case0:
```

The [original Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/notgibs/500-greatest-albums-of-all-time-rolling-stone/) doesn't bother to document it, and the various kernels that use the set all just clobber the encoding. It's clearly a 8-bit Latin-variant (the majority of the data is ASCII with a few individual 8-bit codepoints).

So I analysed the data, and found there are just two such codepoints in 9 rows:

```
>>> import re
>>> eightbit = re.compile(rb'[\x80-\xff]')
>>> with open('albumlist.csv', 'rb') as bindata:
...     nonascii = [l for l in bindata if eightbit.search(l)]
...
>>> len(nonascii)
9
>>> {c for l in nonascii for c in eightbit.findall(l)}
{b'\x89', b'\xca'}
```

The 0x89 byte appears in just one line:

```
>>> sum(l.count(b'\x89') for l in nonascii)
1
>>> sum(l.count(b'\xca') for l in nonascii)
22
>>> next(l for l in nonascii if b'\x89' in l)
b'359,1972,Honky Ch\x89teau,Elton John,Rock,"Pop Rock,\xcaClassic Rock"\r\n'
```

That's clearly [Elton John's 1972 *Honky Château* album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honky_Ch%C3%A2teau), so the 0x89 byte must represent the [U+00E2 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00E2/index.htm) codepoint.

The 0xCA bytes all appear to represent an alternative space character, they all appear righ after commas in the genre and subgenre columns (with one album exception):

```
>>> import csv
>>> for row in csv.reader((l.decode('ascii', 'backslashreplace') for l in nonascii)):
...     for col in row:
...         if '\\' in col: print(col)
...
Reggae,\xcaPop,\xcaFolk, World, & Country,\xcaStage & Screen
Reggae,\xcaRoots Reggae,\xcaRocksteady,\xcaContemporary,\xcaSoundtrack
Electronic,\xcaStage & Screen
Soundtrack,\xcaDisco
Rock,\xcaBlues
Blues Rock,\xcaElectric Blues,\xcaHarmonica Blues
Garage Rock,\xcaPsychedelic Rock
Honky Ch\x89teau
Pop Rock,\xcaClassic Rock
Funk / Soul,\xcaFolk, World, & Country
Rock,\xcaPop
Stan Getz\xca/\xcaJoao Gilberto\xcafeaturing\xcaAntonio Carlos Jobim
Bossa Nova,\xcaLatin Jazz
Lo-Fi,\xcaIndie Rock
```

These 0xCA bytes are almost certainly representing the [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A0/index.htm) codepoint.

With these two mappings, you can try to determine what 8-bit codecs would make the same mapping. Rather than manually try out [all Python's codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) I used [Tripleee's 8-bit codec mapping](https://github.com/tripleee/8bit/) to see what codecs use these mappings. There are only two:

> - 0x89
>
> â‎ (U+00E2):  mac_arabic, mac_croatian, mac_farsi, mac_greek, mac_iceland, mac_roman, mac_romanian, mac_turkish
>
> - 0xca
>
>   ‎ (U+00A0):     mac_centeuro, mac_croatian, mac_cyrillic, mac_greek, mac_iceland, mac_latin2, mac_roman, mac_romanian, mac_turkish

There are 6 encodings that are listed in both sets:

```
>>> set1 = set('mac_arabic, mac_croatian, mac_farsi, mac_greek, mac_iceland, mac_roman, mac_romanian, mac_turkish'.split(', '))
>>> set2 = set('mac_centeuro, mac_croatian, mac_cyrillic, mac_greek, mac_iceland, mac_latin2, mac_roman, mac_romanian, mac_turkish'.split(', '))
>>> set1 & set2
{'mac_turkish', 'mac_iceland', 'mac_romanian', 'mac_greek', 'mac_croatian', 'mac_roman'}
```

Of these, [Mac OS Roman `mac_roman`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) codec is probably the most likely to have been used as Microsoft Excel for Mac [used Mac Roman to create CSV files](https://donatstudios.com/CSV-An-Encoding-Nightmare) for a long time. However, it doesn't really matter, any of those 6 would work here.

You may want to replace those U+00A0 non-breaking spaces if you want to split out the genre and subgenre columns (really the genre and *style* columns if these were taken from Discogs).